# Problema con select valores select js

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haceiendo una funcion que pida un valor por teclado y otro por lista de select y que los multimplique pero no se como hacer para que el js coja el valor de la lista, necesito que la el elemento de la lista tenga un valor y que el js lo multiplique por la cantidad que se introduzca por teclado, dejo el codigo aquí:

```js
function calcular(a,b)
{
 var num=Number(a.value);
 var precio=document.getElementById("b");
 var total;
 var mensaje;
 if(num==0||num<0)
 {
  alert("Introduzca un número valido");
 }
 else if ((precio.value)!=0)
 {
  total=num*(precio.value);
 }
 mensaje="<p>El precio total es: "+total+"€</p>";
 document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML=mensaje;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <p>
   Introduzca la cantidad de producto:
   <input type="number" name="a" size="10"/>
  </p>
  <p>Seleccione el producto</p>
  <select name="b" id="b">
   <option>Patatas Fritas</option>
   <option>Lechuga</option>
  </select>
   <button type="button" onclick="calcular(a,b)">Calcular precio</button>
 </form>
 <div id="salida" class="salida">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo sería un código que quede así:

```js
function calcular(a,b)
{
 var num=Number(a.value);
 var precio=document.getElementById("b");
 var total;
 var mensaje;
 if(num==0||num<0)
 {
  alert("Introduzca un número valido");
 }
 else if ((precio.value)!=0)
 {
  total=num*(precio.value);
 }
 mensaje="<p>El precio total es: "+total+"€</p>";
 document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML=mensaje;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <p>
   Introduzca la cantidad de producto:
   <input type="number" name="a" size="10"/>
  </p>
  <p>Seleccione el producto</p>
  <select name="b" id="b">
   <option value="6">Patatas Fritas</option>
   <option value="3">Lechuga</option>
  </select>
   <button type="button" onclick="calcular(a,b)">Calcular precio</button>
 </form>
 <div id="salida" class="salida">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y en la opción `value` pones el precio que quieras a cada producto. Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregarle valor a cada `option` asi:

```js
function calcular(a,b)
{
 var num=Number(a.value);
 var precio=document.getElementById("b");
 var total;
 var mensaje;
 if(num==0||num<0)
 {
  alert("Introduzca un número valido");
 }
 else if ((precio.value)!=0)
 {
  total=num*(precio.value);
 }
 mensaje="<p>El precio total es: "+total+"€</p>";
 document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML=mensaje;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <p>
   Introduzca la cantidad de producto:
   <input type="number" name="a" size="10"/>
  </p>
  <p>Seleccione el producto</p>
  <select name="b" id="b">
   <option value=1>Patatas Fritas</option>
   <option value=2>Lechuga</option>
  </select>
   <button type="button" onclick="calcular(a,b)">Calcular precio</button>
 </form>
 <div id="salida" class="salida">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```